# How to break up product list by first X amount then from X amount to y then y to z, etc

Tags: magento-1.9, product-list

I am creating a CMS page that lists products from a specific category but I need to break up the list into four. I want to show the first 25 in one list then the next 25 in another, then 40 in a third list and finally any remaining products in the category.

So far I have tried this:

```
$categoryid = 153;

$category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
$category->load($categoryid);
$collection = $category->getProductCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$collection->setPageSize(24);
```

It works but the list starts from the first 24 products each time, how can I start the subsequent list from where the previous list ends?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `->setCurPage(2);` 2 being the 2nd page of the amount of products you selected.